# Zend_Navigation & Zend Router

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am looking for the solution of the problem of combining Zend_Navigation within multilanguagal page-setup with Routers.
I wrote several routers (eg '/:lang/:controller/:action'), which work fine. At the same time I use navigation.xml which has definitions like
`<user>
                  <label>Users</label>
                    <uri>mdm/users</uri>
                </user>`
I have to add dynamically the default language to the navigation. How can I do this?

Thanks a lot,
Anatoliy

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the default language in the route?

```
$router->addRoute('default', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':lang/:controller/:action',
    array(
        'lang'       => 'en',
        'module'     => 'default'
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index'
    )
));
```

Notice that I've replaced the "default" route as your routing scheme would match the default `:module/:controller/:action`

Comment: I did it, I defined several Routes, but if I render my navigation on the first page - eg. mysuperpage.com navigation links look like mysuperpage.com/:controller/:action, which doesnt work as I defined Routes mysuperpage.com/:lang/:controller/:action or mysuperpage.com/:lang/:controller, and on the first page I dont have lang definition. As soon as I switch the lang I have mysuperpage.com/:lang/, then the navigation works great. For the default Route (intro page without any parameters I set default language), after that the navigation is rendered by Zend-Framework, which is without /:lang/.

Comment: and it is exactly the problem ;/